# Jasmine spyOn never been called due to multitone service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spyon

Here's my component:

```
export class QrcodeComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(
   private qrGenService: QrGeneratorService,
  ) {
  }

 private draw(): void {
    this.setOptions();
    this.qrGenService.setInitOptions(this._options);
    this.qrGenService.generateQr();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.draw();
  }
}
```

Here's spec:

```
const qrServiceStub = {
  setInitOptions: () => {},
  generateQr: () => {},
};

describe('QrCodeComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<QrcodeComponent>;
  let component: QrcodeComponent;
  let qrService: QrGeneratorService;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        QrcodeComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: QrGeneratorService, useValue: qrServiceStub },
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QrcodeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    qrService = TestBed.inject(QrGeneratorService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));


  it('should call setInitOptions with options passed & generateQr methods', () => {
    // Arrange
    const setInitOptionsSpy = spyOn(qrService, 'setInitOptions').and.callThrough();
    const generateQrSpy = spyOn(qrService, 'generateQr').and.callThrough();
    // Assert
    expect(setInitOptionsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(component.options);
    expect(generateQrSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

And for some reasons, I got the failed test:

- *Error: Expected spy generateQr to have been called.*
- *Error: Expected spy setInitOptions to have been called with: [ Object ] but it was never called.*

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

**NB qrService is multitone!**

Comment: Try calling onInit after your spys is set, the it will probably work. But you problem is that you are calling onInit before your are doing your assetion, so the spys are set after your onInit is run.

Comment: I did it beforehand and removed ngOnInit calling because it changed nothing

Comment: So calling qrService.onInit(), did not work, after setting the spy's?

Comment: qrService is a service, it doesn't have lifecycle hooks at all. But even after calling component.ngOnInit it still doesn't work

Comment: You are not calling qrService in your test, you are calling the stub, and you are injecting the service into the testbed. try and remove the service shenanigans, and then bind the spy to the service, even tho it's private, but you can just go `spyOn(component['qrGenService'], 'setInitOptions')` that will listen for the service in the component.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I set the spyOn in this way and add component.ngOnInit calling after that. Thanks! 
Do you have any idea why it happened? I have almost the same test that works correctly, but there I injected Service to a TestBed and spied on this service's implementation in Testbed but not on the service which was injected in component itself

Comment: Yes, you are injecting a stub into the component, and then you are injecting the service into the testbed, so the component is calling the stub, and you are spying on the service, so it will never be called since you are looking at two different thing. I would take a guess and say that you are not stubbing the service that you are injecting in the place where it's working.

Comment: You're goddamn right! (Walter White pic's here)
Thank you for your help and explanation!